# Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant in reactjs,redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

I'm new to React and Redux. When I click the submit button Form JSX it will dispatch but it shows the type property undefined. Any idea?

This is the image link of my error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEf3u.jpg

this my store code below

```
 import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
 import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
 import { forbiddenWordsMiddleware } from "../middleware";

 const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || 
 compose;

 const store = createStore(
   rootReducer,
   storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(forbiddenWordsMiddleware))
 );
 export default store;
```

my action code below

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
export function addArticle(payload) {
  return { type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload };
}
```

here is my Form component looks like below code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import uuidv1 from "uuid";
import { addArticle } from "../actions/index";

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        addArticle: article => dispatch(addArticle(article))
    };
}
class ConnectedForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { title } = this.state;
        const id = uuidv1();
        this.props.addArticle({ title, id });
        this.setState({ title: "" });
    }
    render() {
        const { title } = this.state;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="title"
                        value={title}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                    SAVE
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
const Form = connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ConnectedForm);
export default Form;
```

Comment: it seems there is a problem here: "import {ADD_ARTICLE} from" ../constants/action-types ";". ADD_ARTICLE can not be empty and must return a string

Comment: You can test :
`import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
export function addArticle(payload) {
console.log("ADD_ARTICLE :",ADD_ARTICLE )
  return { type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload };
} `

That's the result in console ?

Comment: hi @A.Vincent ADD_ARTICLE is a const of type string

Comment: thanks @A.Vincent it returns undefined.whats the solution?

Comment: maybe in your action-types `export const ADD_ARTICLE = "ADD_ARTICLE" ` ?
In my case i use an objet and i export him : `const actions = {ADD_ARTICLE:"ADD_ARTICLE", OTHER_KEY:"OTHER_VALUE"}  export default actions ` in my file action : `import actions from "../constants/action-types"; export function addArticle(payload) { return { type: actions.ADD_ARTICLE, payload }; } `

Comment: Can you please add your `action-types.js` file here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ADD_ARTICLE` type should be in quotes like so:

```
// Action creator
export const addArticle = (article) => {
  // returns an action
  return {
    type: 'ADD_ARTICLE',
    payload: article
  };
};
```

Notice how I implement the `payload` as well, you may want to take a look at that too.

Additionally, study and review ES6 syntax so you can avail yourself of the power of arrow functions and avoid having to use so many `bind(this)` and subsequently have cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapDispatchToProps method is wrong. It must be something like below:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {        
   addArticle 
}
```